# Close own uiviewcontroller after segue to child uiviewcontroller ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, unwind-segue

I have three UIViewControllers (let's call them A, B and C) in a navigation controller. A can segue into either B or C. B can segue into C. When C closes, I want it to always return to A, i.e. it automatically closes B upon closing C, if opened from B.

Now, I tried using segue unwinding, so that when C closes, B's return method gets called to dismiss the destination controller:

```
- (IBAction)returnFromC:(UIStoryboardSegue*)segue
{
    [segue.destinationViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I put a breakpoint in this method - it is called. I have verified that the destinationController is indeed B. However, I noticed when the break point hits, C is still visible. After playing from the break point, C does exit as expected, but B is still visible.

Any ideas? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When C closes, I want it to always return to A, i.e. it automatically closes B upon closing C, if opened from B

The simplest solution is: in C's `viewDidAppear:`, secretly remove B as a child of the navigation controller. In other words, you've got this:

```
A > B > C
```

Now you rearrange things so that you've got this:

```
A > C
```

Thus, the only thing to go back to from C is A.

It's easy to manipulate the navigation controller's set of children in this way. Just call `setViewControllers:animated:` (with a second argument of NO).

[But if I've understood your setup properly, another easy way would be to implement the unwind method in A and not B. Then do an unwind segue. We always unwind to the first view controller that contains the unwind method, so that would always be A.]

Comment: The way to actually do this is to make a mutable copy of the navigation controller's `viewControllers` property, remove the controller, and then assign the array back to the navigation controller.

Comment: I used the suggestion of putting the unwind method in A. I didn't understand that unwind works over multiple VCs. Many thanks for your quick prompt response.

Comment: @iht Very cool. Unwind is extremely complex and powerful and highly configurable, and placement of the unwind method is the simplest and most basic part of that configuration. It's great that that little clue was enough to solve it for you!

Answer (score 0):

`dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` is used to dismiss a **Modal segue** and has no effect for **Push segues**

As @matt suggested you could just remove B (the middle) view controller from `self.navigationController.viewControllers` and here's a sample code that you can put in B view controller:

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];

    // No need to process if the viewController is already being removed
    if (!self.isMovingFromParentViewController) {
        // Getting a mutable copy of the viewControllers (can't directly modify)
        NSMutableArray *temp = [self.navigationController.viewControllers mutableCopy];

        // Removing 'self' -> so A > B > C will become A > C
        [temp removeObject:self];

        // Setting the new array of viewControllers
        self.navigationController.viewControllers = [temp copy]; // getting an immutable copy
    }
}
```

**P.S.** You could use `popViewControllerAnimated:` instead of **Unwind segue** if you're not planning to send the data back.